# Type conversion from (type *int) to type int

Tags: pointers, int, type-conversion, go

I want to convert a pointer `*int` to its real value `int`, in Go language.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `*` operator. For example:

```
var i  int = 10  // `i` is an integer, with value 10
var p *int = &i  // `p` is a pointer to an integer, its value is a memory address
var n  int = *p  // `n` is again an integer, with value 10
```

Once you get the hang of what's happening, the above code can be written in a more idiomatic (and simpler)  way like this, assuming that we're inside a function:

```
i := 10
p := &i
n := *p
```

Comment: These are not idiomatic. It is very rare that someone would do `var p *int = &i` in go. Normally you would do `p := &i`. `var n int = *p` would then just be `n := *p`

Comment: @StephenWeinberg I know, but given the question I wanted to make explicit the type of each variable

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Anyway. I updated my answer to reflect the more idiomatic way to write the same code.