# From flag how do you return an (int) instead of an (*int)?

Tags: go

This program returns:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    num_agents := flag.Int("a", 10, "number of agents")
    flag.Parse();

    fmt.Printf("%#v",num_agents)
}
```

Outputs

```
(*int)(0x18600110)`
```

However that is not what I want... What I want is the integer.

So according to the documentation seems I should use flag.IntVar(&pointer_to_variable_integer)

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var num_agents int
    flag.IntVar(&num_agents,"a", 10, "number of agents")
    flag.Parse();

    fmt.Printf("%#v",num_agents)
}
```

However that doesn't seem right... Because I need to write 2 lines of code when 1 should do.
somehow it seems to me that

```
num_agents := flags.Int("a", 10, "number of agents")
```

Should return an int instead of *int.?
 Or maybe there is an easy way to cast from *int to int ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply dereference the pointer:

```
num_agents := flags.Int("a", 10, "number of agents")
fmt.Println(*num_agents)
```

Comment: Yeap thanks to other question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075408/type-conversion-from-type-int-to-type-int/11075463#11075463

I'm starting to understand what is going on :-) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
var num_agents int

func init() {
    flag.IntVar(&num_agents, "a", 10, "number of agents")
}
```